# how to make vuejs click event to be synchronous

Tags: javascript, vue.js, click

i have this html

```
 <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" @click="decrement(item)">-</span>
                  </div>

                  <input type="text" v-model="item.quantity" class="form-control w-25" aria-label="Product quantity">

                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text" @click="increment(item)">+</span>
                  </div>
```

It creates an input element like:

[image]

When user clicks on '+' or '-' i am calling increment(item) or decrement(item) Vuejs methods, in that methods i am calling updateCart function:

```
async  updateCart(item, quantity){
                let q = quantity + item.quantity;
                let data = {
                    quantity: q,
                    id: item.key
                }
                let startedQuantity=q; 
               let json = await axios.post('/cart/change.js', data );               
               if(json.status === 200){
```

As you can see in that function i have axios.post call, after that call i am waiting for result and putting the result to json variable. The problem is: when user clicks on + or - multiple times click event is not synchronous, it didn't wait until first click is processed after that process second click. How can i make click event to be synchronous. Thanks

Comment: Whenever a user will click multiple times on a button, it will be hit multiple times. because the functions is being called multiple times. You just disable the click event if click has already been triggered and if response comes back enable it again

Comment: Abdul Basit Thank you for your response. As you said i have  disabled the click event if click has already been triggered and if response comes back enabled it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make the event synchronous. Even if you could do it, this will make the UI freeze, which not what you want.

A better approach is to `disable` the button while the request is in flight and enable it back after you get a response. Because you're using divs you could style it differently depending on the state of the requests.

Add a `loading` flag on your `data`

```
data() {
 return {
   ...
   loading: false
 }
}
```

Set css class depending on the flag's value

```
<div class="input-group-prepend"
     v-bind:class="{ disabled: loading }" >
```

Update the flag from your methods

```
async updateCart(item, quantity){
  if(this.loading) {
   return
  }

  this.loading = true

  let q = quantity + item.quantity;
  let data = {
    quantity: q,
    id: item.key
  }
  let startedQuantity=q; 
  let json = await axios.post('/cart/change.js', data );  

  this.loading = false
  ...
```

Comment: Radu Diță, Thank you, i have solved the issue using your approach